# How do I execute a method at a particular time in java?

Tags: java, methods, cron, jobs

Is there any way to write a program in java, so that its main method schedule (or at a 10-15 min interval) another method to executes it at a particular interval?

Comment: You can use a Scheduler http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: You could use a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Time class.

See  [Timer Class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)
You can use this class like:

You want to perform a Method every 600 miliseconds. You write:

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
                //Do your stuff
                }
            };

Timer t = new Timer(600, taskPerfomer);
t.start;
```

There are more options. This example will be executed once but it can be executed in an interval.
I hope it helps.

Comment: This solution only execute the method single time. If you want to execute it at particulate interval you must use schedulers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Job scheduler for this. i.e.
**Quartz Job Scheduler**.

Refer this [Quartz API](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Or
You can use **ScheduledExecutorService Java Interface**

Refer this [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use Scheduled Thread pool executor:
Schedual your worker thread to execute at every 10 Seconds
scheduledThreadPool.schedule(worker, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

1) Class WorkerThread .java

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable{

private String command;

    public WorkerThread(String s){
        this.command=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start. Time = "+new Date());
        processCommand();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End. Time = "+new Date());
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.command;
    }
}
```

2) Class ScheduledThreadPool .java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class ScheduledThreadPool {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);


        //schedule to run after sometime
        System.out.println("Current Time = "+new Date());
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread("do heavy processing");
            scheduledThreadPool.schedule(worker, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        //add some delay to let some threads spawn by scheduler
        Thread.sleep(30000);

        scheduledThreadPool.shutdown();
        while(!scheduledThreadPool.isTerminated()){
            //wait for all tasks to finish
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your task is not so big, you can use `Thread.sleep()` method(example 10 iteration with 10 minutes delay):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   methodOne();

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     Thread.sleep(600000);
     methodTwo();
   }
}
```